# Problem with ResourceBundle in servlet

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, internationalization

I want to display a localized message with my servlet (in Google App Engine) but i get the message in the wrong language, french instead of english.

I have 2 resource files Messages.properties (english = default) and Messages_fr.properties (french). The browser language is set to english. `request.getLocale()` is "en" but `ResourceBundle.getBundle("Messages",request.getLocale()).getLocale()` is "fr".

I don't understand what's happening. Any help is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a **physically existing** `Messages_en.properties` file. It can be left empty so that it will fallback to `Messages.properties`.

Comment: You're right, it works :) This is strange because I have some Java experience and I never noticed this behavior. Is it something specific to Google App Engine?

Comment: @Patrick, @Balus: No, it's standard behavior. See the [getBundle()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29) docs.

Comment: Ah right, it will also test using the platform default locale. Patrick's is apparently also French.

Comment: Yes. The other solution would be to call `Locale.setDefault(request.getLocale())`.

Comment: ... But I just noticed `Locale.setDefault` is not allowed by GAE :-/ So I'll use your "hack" finally.